# Htaccess rewrite from one file to another

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect all queries to file 1.php to file 2.php. So I need if somebody will ask 1.php server will give him 2.php. 1.php and 2.php are in the same folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^2.php 1.php
```

This code in htaccess doesn't work. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?[the folder]/1.php$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ [the folder]/2.php [L]
```

Comment: And what if I would like to put my .htaccess in the same folder with 1.php and 2.php? How should I change this code? Thanks!

Comment: It won't work, `.htaccess` has to be in the `root` folder (configured in `httpd.conf`), meaning, if your domain is: `www.domain.com` then `.htacess` should be here: `www.domain.com/.htacess`