# htaccess Redirect One File to Another

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226168/htaccess-rewrite-from-one-file-to-another) and this seems too long for my request.

And tried `Redirect /index.php /index2.php` but it didn't work (Internal Server error)

What I want is to redirect some of my php files to index. For example, I've my index file as

header.php

content.php

footer.php

and I want to redirect direct access to this files to index.php. Is it possible with htaccess or any other way?

mysite.com/index.php OK
mysite.com/header.php redirect to 404 or index or something else.

Comment: What do you mean by "direct access"? All of your files that get served by a webserver is directly accessed.

Comment: I thought I expalin well. I'm creating my design with php include method. I want to block direct access to my included file. I want to block some files - in this case, header.php and footer.php - blocked. If anybody tries to visit my pages, it's allright. If anybody tried to access my header.php by www.example.com/header.php I want to redirect them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(header|content|footer)\.php - [L,R=404]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(header|content|footer)\.php index.php [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I did RewriteRule ^(header|content|footer)\.php index.php [L,NC] and seems ok. Should I use parameters such ac 301 404 etc? Are they neccesary?

Comment: @Degauser the "R" flag redirects. The 404 means return a "404 Not Found" error, the 301 means permanently redirect.