# Deny access to certain webpage

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii2

i have a proyect in Yii2 so what i want to do is deny/block some webpages of my proyect
How can it do it with .htaccess or it's better using an if statement and then redirect them to certain path.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23184738/htaccess-redirect-one-file-to-another).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using .htaccess, the most convenient way would be to use a Rewrite Rule.

You can do this by using a rewrite rule to forbid access to **certain files**.

```
RewriteRule "^path/to/file\.php$" "-" [F]
```

Or you can do the same with **whole directories**.

```
RewriteRule "^/path/to/secret/files/" "-" [F]
```