# Very basic htaccess pretty URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having trouble redirecting a hard coded URL to a pretty URL.

I want to access the following url :

```
mysite.com/index.php?page=links
```

By navigating to :

```
mysite.com/links/
```

I've read a whole bunch of other questions on this topic but they all relate to dynamic data being passed through the url with strings. I just want a simple htaccess RewriteRule that will only affect this specific url and nothing else.

I've tried a ton of stuff but nothing is working, 404's every time.

Example :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^links/ index.php?page=links
```

Any help appreciated.

EDIT - reacting to the suggested answer offered. This is totally NOT what I'm looking to do. I'm NOT trying to redirect one page to another, I simply want to rewrite the URL in the browser.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `.htaccess`, mod_rewrite and `FollowSymLinks` are enabled? Do you have other directives in `.htaccess`? Any other `.htaccess` files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess Redirect One File to Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23184738/htaccess-redirect-one-file-to-another)

Comment: Hi, yes mod_rewrite and FollowSymLinks are enabled. No other .htaccess files. Only other directive is `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?page=error&action=404` which works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. apache2.conf wasn't allowing the override so I added the following.

```
<Directory /var/www/html/public/>
   Options Indexes FollowSysmLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Is this safe?

Answer (score 0):

index.php

```
<?php

  define('BASE_URL', '/mysite.com/');

  if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    echo "query string ==> $_SERVER[QUERY_STRING]" . "<br />";
  } else {
    echo "Not query 'page'" . "<br />";         
  } 

  echo "url ==> $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"  . "<br />";

?>

<a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>">index</a><br/>
<a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>1">1</a><br/>
<a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>2">2</a><br/>
<a href="index.php?page=3">3</a><br/>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

#RegEx pattern matching => query string
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1
```